# Nilpotent elements in ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $f:R\rightarrow S$ be a ring homomorphism, if $x\in R$ is a nilpotent element, then $f(x)$ is also nilpotent with a nilpotent degree smaller/equal to the nilpotent degree of.
That statement is easy to proof and I dont have a problem with it.
My question is that:
Is the nilpotent degree of $f(x)$ **divides** the nilpotent degree of $x$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not necessarily. Take $k[x]/(x^3)\to k[y]/(y^2)$ defined by sending $x\mapsto y$. Then $x^3=0$, while $y^2=0$ but $2\nmid 3$.

Comment: Thank you! just another question to be sure: elements in the ring $k[x]/(x^3)$ are of the form $ax^2+bx+c+(x^3)$?

Comment: Yes. Or, if you use $\overline{x}$ to represent the coset of $x$, they are of the form $a\overline{x}^2+b\overline{x}+c$.